# Inno Setup - Installer for multiple installers

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I have two setups for my applications - one is for 32 bit systems, the second one - for 64 bit. I wanted to automatically install one of them on user's system, so I have created another setup (let's name it SuperSetup), that takes my two setups and choose which one to install (using Check: IsWin64 / not IsWin64). Basically SuperSetup is very simple, and it's used only to run one of my setups, it doesn't need to install anything by itself.
All wizard pages of SuperSetup are hidden except first and last, basically if user clicks "Install" it copies one of my setups to {tmp}, then activate it. Everything works great, but after installation is done I find two applications in my "programs and features" menu - the one that I wanted to install (which is great), and the one named SuperSetup (which is trash). Is there any way to avoid installation of SuperSetup, or remove it after installation is complete?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions about my problem, sorry for my english tho ;]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [`Uninstallable`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_uninstallable) directive value to `no`. The reference describes it as:

> This determines if Inno Setup's automatic uninstaller is to be
>   included in the installation. If this is yes or to a boolean
>   expression evaluating to True the uninstaller is included. Otherwise,
>   no uninstallation support is included, requiring the end-user to
>   manually remove the files pertaining to your application.

And since you are not copying any files, but just run one of the included setups, you don't need to worry about the final note nor need the uninstaller at all:

```
[Setup]
...
Uninstallable=no
```

Comment: P.S. cleaning up the setup's temporary folder remains working of course. That note about manual file removing applies to files that you would install somewhere in the system, not to files that you extract to a temporary folder.